# ActionScript 3.0 Augment Error #2015: Invalid BitmpData

Tags: actionscript-3

I encountered this error on my test run. I do not know what caused it.

Output Counsol:

ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData.

at flash.display::BitmapData/ctor()

at flash.display::BitmapData()

at com.efg.framework::BlitSprite()

at com.efg.framework::TileByTileBlitSprite()

at com.efg.games.notanks::GameDemoIteration1/init()

at com.efg.games.notanks::GameDemoIteration1()

```
        bitmapData = new BitmapData(tileWidth, tileHeight, true, 0x00000000);
        bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
        bitmap.x = -.5 * tileWidth;
        bitmap.y = -.5 * tileHeight;
        addChild(bitmap);
        currentTile = firstFrame;
        renderCurrentTile(true);
```

Comment: Reduce the amount of code you post to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I really don't know what went wrong. this is all the files that was marked by the error counsol.

Comment: Go to Control > Test Movie > in Flash (Or Ctrl/Command + Shift + Enter/Return) to debug, and paste in the line(s) that it says are giving you trouble.

Comment: This is what is called the "wall of code", but your post is missing the relevant classes that actually are doing anything notable. For example, TileByTileBlitSprite just calls super(), so that is not useful. You'll want to check that TankSheepPng actually is working correctly, that it has a valid bitmap to load. You are getting this error usually by either not drawing the bitmapData object, or setting the width and height to 0. It looks like the latter is probably not the case, so you'll need to verify that TankSheepPng is setup correctly.

Comment: I cleaned up the code abit and i left only what i think relates to the problem

Answer (score 0):

BitmapData/ctor() is thrown if you try to create a BitmapData with invalid data. So the problem is there.

Start using debugger and breakpoints to see what params are you passing to those classes. We're not magicians and can't guess :)